# Command pattern and complex operations in C#

Tags: c#, .net, undo, command-pattern

I am writing a program in C# that needs to support undo/redo. For this purpose, I settled on the Command pattern; tldr, every operation that manipulates the document state must be performed by a Command object that knows about the previous state of the document as well as the changes that need to be made, and is capable of doing/undoing itself.

It works fine for simple operations, but I now have an operation that affects several parts of the document at once. Likewise, the Command object must be smart enough to know all the old state it needs to preserve in case it needs to be undone.

The problem is exposing all that state using public interfaces has the potential for misuse if someone attempts to call the interface directly, which can lead to state corruption. My insticts tell me the most OO way of doing this is to expose specialized Command classes -- rather than allowing you to directly manipulate the state of the document, all you can do is ask the document to create a Command object which has access to its internal state and is guaranteed to know enough to properly support undo/redo.

Unfortunately, C# doesn't support the concept of friends, so I can't create a Command class that has access to document internals. Is there a way to expose the private members of the document class to another class, or is there some other way to do what I need without having to expose a lot of document internals?

Comment: Normally you would use the Memento pattern when dealing with undo/redo operations and not the command pattern. The command pattern is more suitable when you need to "execute something", when programming a remote control then each button would get a command for instance.

Comment: 'Unfortunately, C# doesn't support the concept of friends' should read 'Fortunately'. Having the language help you shoot yourself in the foot is not any better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, if you are deploying a library your Document could declare 'internal' methods to interact with it's internal state, these methods would be used by you Command class, internal methods are limited to the assembly they are compiled.

Or you could nest a private class to your Document, that way allowing it to access Document's internal state and expose a public interface to it, your Document would then create a command class hidden by that interface.

Comment: Both are completely unextendable solutions.

Comment: @OndrejTucny True but not necessarily a problem, if he wants complete isolation from the user interface he can't extend the Command class from the user code, now if he wants to extend the Command pattern to other undoable classes reusing 'Command' then I agree he needs to expose an interface that all of the classes can use to undo the changes themselves whatever the data type is but this will move the undo action away from the Command.

Answer (score 2):

First, C# has the `internal` keyword that declares "friend" accessibility, which allows public access from within the entire assembly.

Second, the "friend" accessibility [can be extended to a second assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) with an assembly attribute, `InternalsVisibleTo`, so that you could create a **second project** for your commands, and yet the internals of the document will stay internal.

Alternatively, if your command objects are nested inside the document class, then they will have access to all its private members.

Finally, complex commands could also simply clone the document before making changes. That is an easy solution, albeit not very optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You could always access fields and properties, private or not, through reflection ([`Type.GetField(string, BindingFlags.Private)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx) & friends).

Maybe with a custom attribute on the class (or the field/property) to automate the process of grabbing enough state for each Command?

Comment: You can do a thing != You should do this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a command doing changes at different places of the document, you could have two dummy commands that mark the start and end of multi-step operations. Let us call them BeginCommand and EndCommand. First, you push the BeginCommand on the undo-stack, and then you perform the different steps as single commands, each of them doing a change at a single place of the document only. Of cause, you push them on the undo-stack as well. Finally, you push the EndCommand on the undo-stack.

When undoing, you check whether the command popped from the undo stack is the EndCommand. If it is, you continue undoing until the BeginCommand is reached.

This turns the multi-step command into a macro-command delegating the work to other commands. This macro-command itself is not pushed on the undo stack.